# Частота букв в українських текстах

Tags: статистика

Цікавлять дослідження на тему частоти букв української абетки в наших текстах. Поки знайшов

> [image]
>
> Добрий день, Архімеде! Цікаві задачі, ігри, головоломки / А. Г. Конфорович. — К. : Молодь, 1988.

Comment: В епоху комп'ютерів насправді дуже легко провести власне дослідження. Завантажити будь-яку електронну бібліотеку + простий скрипт (Пітон, Ява і т. д.)

Comment: @Vitalii а чи будь-яка електронна бібліотека прийнятно представляє українську мову?

Comment: То є філософське питання. Якщо ваша мета - кріптологія (як була в мене, бо я є за освітою експерт з комп'ютерної безпеки), то так, прийнятно представляє. Якщо у вас інша мета - то вам слід дати визначення "мови". В криптології мова - це протокол обміну інформацією між людьми, без врахування грамматики і т. д. Мова - це те. що ми повинні дешифрувати, хоч би грамотна вона, хоч би ні.

Answer (score 3):

[ЧАСТОТИ ПОВТОРЮВАНОСТІ БУКВ І БІГРАМ У ВІДКРИТИХ ТЕКСТАХ УКРАЇНСЬКОЮ МОВОЮ.](https://drukaryk.com/media/userfiles/source/Oryhinaljna%20stattia.pdf)
С. О. Сушко , Л. Я. Фомичова , Є. С. Барсуков.

> Тексти вибирались зі сторінок україномовних сайтів і належать до п’яти стилів
> сучасної української мови, розмовно-побутового, художнього, наукового, публіцистичного
> та ділового). Загальний обʼєм текстів склав 900123 слів (приблизно 6 Мб)

[image]

---

[АРТИКУЛЯЦІЙНІ ТАБЛИЦІСЛІВ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9TRHiuSzTGwJ:https://ela.kpi.ua/bitstream/123456789/9689/3/06.pdf&cd=3&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua&lr=-lang_ru) Олена Архипова, Володимир Журавльов, В’ячеслав Кумейко